# How can I get an item from an object without title in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to learn some powershell. I want to get only the SSID from a connected network.
My code is : `netsh wlan sh int | select-string SSID | select -First 1`.
The output is `SSID                   : ABCDEFG`. My output must be just `ABCDEFG`. `SSID` doesn't have a title so I don't know how I can select his value `ABCDEFG`.

My first question: **How can I select the value `ABCDEFG` from my object `SSID` and put only the value in my output?**
My second question: **Is the output from my code always a connect network or not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
(Get-NetConnectionProfile).Name
```

which will return just the name of the profile as:

`SSIDNAME`

If there's more than one network connection then you'd need to specify which one you want.

You can grabbing the Wi-Fi interface names with:

```
(Get-NetConnectionProfile | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq "Wi-Fi").Name
```

which will also return the name of the profile (if found) as:

`SSIDNAME`

These are a few ways you can do it using strictly powershell's `netadapter` and `netconnection`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netconnection/?view=windowsserver2022-ps#netconnection

Answer (score 3):

netsh is a traditional command line tool. In contrast to PowerShell cmdlets, which output structured objects, it outputs lines of text.

`Select-String` gets you one of those lines (the one that has "SSID" on it).

You could split it at the colon and take the latter part.

```
$ssid_line = netsh wlan sh int | select-string SSID | select -First 1
$ssid = $ssid_line -split ':' | select -Last 1

Write-Host $ssid
```

Use `$ssid.Trim()` to remove any excess whitespace.

Comment: you likely will have a leading space in there. [*grin*] i suggest using `.Trim()` on it before you assign it to the $Var.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That's why I suggested it. But also I wanted to emphasize incremental improvements and the difference between getting the property of an object, and getting the last part of a string split.

Comment: @Tomalak - i somehow managed to NOT see that. [*blush*] /lee goes back to lurking ...